# Найти максимальную сумму k чисел в числовой последовательности за 1 секунду - C#

Tags: c#

Не могу уложиться в одну секунду.

В первой строке входных данных содержится пара целых чисел n и k (1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 10^5) — количество чисел в последовательности и количество чисел, сумму которых нужно найти.
Во второй строке дана последовательность из n целых чисел a1, a2, ..., an (1 ≤ ai ≤ 1000).
Числа в этой последовательности разделены одинарными пробелами.

В первую строку вывести нужно максимальную среднюю сумму среди всех непрерывных отрезков длины k в виде несократимой дроби «s/k».
Во вторую строку нужно вывести количество таких отрезков длины k, на которых достигается это максимальное значение.

Примеры:

**входные данные**

3 2

1 3 1

**выходные данные**

2/1

2

**входные данные**

4 3

1 2 3 3

**выходные данные**

8/3

1

Мое решение:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp182
{
class Program
{
    static int gcd(int a, int b)
    {
        return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b); // нод
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string current = "";
        int q = 0;
        int S = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int z = 1;
        List<string> row = new List<string>();
        List<int> introw = new List<int>();
        current = Console.ReadLine();
        row = current.Split(' ').ToList<string>();
        q = int.Parse(row[1]);
        current = Console.ReadLine();
        row = current.Split(' ').ToList<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Count; i++)
        {
            introw.Add(int.Parse(row[i]));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < introw.Count - q + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < q; j++)
            {
                S = S + introw[i + j];
            }
            if (S > max)
            {
                max = S;
                z = 1;
            }
            else if (S == max)
            {
                z++;
            }
            S = 0;
        }
        int a = max;
        int b = q;
        int d = gcd(a, b);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", a / d, b / d);
        Console.WriteLine(z);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: И? Предлагаете за вас олимпиадную задачку решать?

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов, забыл код в шапку приложить

Comment: Ну приложили код, дальше что?

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов, в секунду не могу уложиться, как оптимизировать, я же вопрос написал в шапку

Comment: Подумайте, как обойтись без полного перебора

Comment: Возьмите комп по-мощнее :)

Comment: Тестировщик - программа задание проверяет

Comment: gcd неправильно написан.

Comment: HasmikGaryaka, у меня все работает, за секунду не укладывается только

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов в сабже у вас задание, типа "Апорт" или "Сидеть". Чуть ниже вы проблему излагаете. Вопроса нет.

Comment: Может и работает, для маленького b, а попробуйте a=5 b=25

Comment: Попробовал, все работает с a=5 b=25

Comment: Как уложиться то в секунду?

Comment: Сделайте так. Посчитайте первую сумму. Потом, чтобы найти вторую,  вычитаем первое слагаемое и добавляем следующее. Для больших q даст выигрыш.

Comment: HasmikGaryaka, а вы можете сделать, а то я не совсем понимаю о чем речь

Comment: Каждый шаг вместо O(n) будет O(1)

Comment: S2 = S1 + introw[q+1]-introw[0]

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас вы для нахождения суммы чисел с i до i+q пишете цикл

```
            for (int j = 0; j < q; j++)
            {
                S = S + introw[i + j];
            }
```

Но у вас есть сумма, полученная на предыдущем шаге. Это сумма чисел от i-1 до i-1+q. Большая часть слагаемый у этих сумм общая. Отличается лишь первое и последнее слагаемое.
Поэтому S-introw[i-1]+introw[i+q-1] даст нужную сумму. Отказ от цикла ускорит программу.

Comment: Нету, я как раз сумму в цикле получаю

Comment: Первую сумму в цикле, дальше можно плюс минусом.
Вот в примере 1 2 3 3 сумма длина 3. Первая сумма =1+2+3=6. Вторая сумма (1+2+3)-1+3=6-1+3=8.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, уложился в секунду

Comment: @Сергей Бекмамбетов, поставьте зеленую галочку у своего вопроса, дабы он не мозолил глаза, как не отвеченный, а Ваш благодетель получил дополнительные балы в "карму".

Comment: @Сергей, возможность ставить галочку никогда не ограничивается из-за низкой репутации.